ACM TAPS compatible package for type inference rules
I want to write inference rules like with \inference from the semantic package,
but that package is not ACM TAPS compatible.  Is there an ACM TAPS accepted package that lets me do that (more easily than nested arrays and \hline and \raisebox, etc.)?
(Note that none of proof, ebproof or bussproofsis TAPS compatible.)
Simple example that shows 2 lines above the horizontal line:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}

\begin{document}

\inference
    {A = B & B = C \\
      C = D }
    {A = D}

\end{document}



welcome! email the address they give and ask them what they suggest using. that's rather a strange list, to my way of thinking. if there's a package in the list you've missed, fine. if not, they need to either evaluate the package you prefer or, failing that, identify and evaluate an alternative. or else they want you to do something hacky, but that's a lot more trouble for them than adding a suitable package to the list.

just looking at the doc, semantic uses the picture environment, so it isn't as if it is dragging in something huge such as pgf. that should make it fairly straightforward to evaluate, I'd think. they'd be allowing a pretty limited amount of new stuff, so should be fairly easy to test compatibility. otherwise, you could just make a custom environment to do this, but I'd ask them first.

Thanks for the comments. Agreed, one should email the address (which I did).  They responded quickly saying they would look into it but did not yet offer an alternative.  Until then, I'm still looking for an alternative.

are you allowed to define new macros in your preamble? if so, you could just copy what you need from the package. sorry, I don't know every package on their list but I see no obvious alternative there and I'm not going to investigate them all because an institution insists on an outdated and highly restricted set of packages. The only thing I can really suggest is to compile them as images and include those or makedo with tabular/array environments. I don't see you have many options here. there is no shortage of alternative packages to do the job. but not, that I see, on their list.

if you've not checked the LaTeX for Logicians site, maybe at least look there first. that's as comprehensive as coverage gets for logic-related packages. if this kind of format is used in other disciplines, you could try searching those by topic on ctan with the list of approved packages to hand for reference. if the journal(s) already have papers with this kind of format, either consult the source or email the author(s) and ask what they used. sorry, but that about exhausts my suggestions. of course you can spin something yourself, but where's the difference with copying from the .sty?
